# How to use URL Re-write to direct one category to another?

Tags: url, redirect

How do I use URL Re-write to direct one category to another? I have found a tutorial on how to do a custom URL re-write one how to direct a category to a CMS page. Is there an easy way to direct category to category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same you do for redirecting a category page to a cms page.
Just put in the target path of your custom url rewrite the url of the target category.

Comment: In my URL re-write, should I put the target path as wall-lights/spotlights or catalog/category/view/id/95 ?

Comment: In target you should put the url you want to see in the browser.

Comment: when I try this I get an `Request Path for Specified Store already exists.` error.  I wonder why, I've found the System URL rewrite with the same Request Path, but I can't edit it.  When I delete it I can set my own URL rewrite but when I index a new url rewrite is created which appends a number to the original URL

Comment: This is the case with Magento. When reindexing, Magento will overwrite the custom URL rewrites you've created for categories with system category rewrites which it thinks are more accurate.